# Remove RealmObject Class

Tags: java, android, realm

I doing Realm database in my project. When your using Realm you need to extends simple object to RealmObject. I have a question: How can I create an object without extends RealmObject but I also using Realm database.﻿

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

> An alternative to extending the RealmObject base class is implementing
>   the RealmModel interface and adding the @RealmClass annotation.
>
> ```
> @RealmClass 
> public class User implements RealmModel {
>
> }
> ```
>
> All methods available on RealmObject are then available through
>   static methods.
>
> ```
> // With RealmObject
> user.isValid(); 
> user.addChangeListener(listener);
>
> // With RealmModel
> RealmObject.isValid(user);
> RealmObject.addChangeListener(user, listener);
> ```

Do read the docs, it has a lot of high quality information.

Comment: but a List<Object> is not supported when u implements Realm Model

Comment: I know. Besides u have another solution to use List<Object> replace for RealmList or not.